# Inner While Loop runs only once - Python

Tags: python

I am using Nested While Loops for a program and I have noticed that the inner while loop runs only once.

```
i = 0
j = 0
while i < 5:
    while j < 5:
        print('Inner While Loop')
        j += 1
    print('Outer While Loop')
    i = i+1
```

Output :

```
Inner While Loop
Inner While Loop
Inner While Loop
Inner While Loop
Inner While Loop
Outer While Loop
Outer While Loop
Outer While Loop
Outer While Loop
Outer While Loop
```

What I want is that the inner loop to also run again when the outer loop starts again.

Comment: Initialize j=0 outside the inner loop. Because j got incremented and is no longer 0 after execution of inner loop for first time, you have to again initialize j=0 after inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're not resetting the j variable. So the next time the outer loop executes, j is still 5 and you skip the inner loop. As an example, if you change your code to initialize j inside the first while loop, I believe everything should work:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    j = 0 # Moved to inside the while loop
    while j < 5:
        print('Inner While Loop')
        j += 1
    print('Outer While Loop')
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare `j=0` inside the i loop

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    j = 0
    while j < 5:
        print('Inner While Loop')
        j += 1
    print('Outer While Loop')
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this, you cannot have your code in this format, as it is inefficient. Using the `for` statement will give you better results as the loop continues automatically while increasing the index values, which in your case are `i` and `j`. The `range()` function returns a sequence of numbers, which, when combined with the `for` parameter, allows you to create a loop

This is what you want:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        print('Inner While Loop')
    print('Outer While Loop')
```

Comment: While `for` loops probably are better for this specific example, it's worth noting that not all `while` loops can easily be converted. If `j` only increments some of the time, for instance, you'd struggle to replicate the loop's behavior with `for`.